# Is it possible to create a menu item and leverage path aliases?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks, path-aliases

I am trying to create a menu item that loads a view mode that calls the callback function with the path alias.

```
$items['node/%/%'] = array(
  'page callback' => '_node_view_load',
  'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
 );

function _node_view_load($node_id, $view_mode = 'default') {
  return drupal_render(node_view(node_load($node_id), $view_mode));
}
```

This works if you go to /node/%/view_mode. However, it does not work if you got to /alias/view_mode. I get page not found. Is there a way to bind menu items to path aliases?

Comment: I would rather use `node/%node/%`, and the call to `node_load()` would not be necessary; the last `%` is a catch-all, and it could match paths already defined by other modules.

Comment: How did you create the alias? If "test-page" is the alias for "/node/1," when you visit http://example.com/test-page you will see the content of http://example.com/node/1, which means the callback associated with "/node/%node" is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to extend the pathauto system to handle your specific pattern, like it does for node/x/feed items.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Sub-path URL Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias) module will do what you want.